# UIPath: Export scraped information to a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, automation, screen-scraping, desktop, uipath

I am fairly new to UiPath Studio and I'm wondering how to export scraped information to a spreadsheet. After I use the screen scraping tool, it adds this to my sequence:
[image: scraping sequence]

Now which action do I add to export this into an Excel/CSV file?

Comment: You extract data from a website and want to export it to an Excel file?

Comment: Its not from a website, but a desktop application

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create an `Excel Application Scope`.

There you place the `Write Cell` activity of the specific Sheet and Cell.

[image: UiPath process]

Answer (score 1):

What type of screen scraping are you doing? Web scraping or PDF scraping perhaps?

Regardless of which one you choose, UiPath will bring the information back in the form of a data table. DataTables work well with CSV flies and Excel spreadsheets.

### Excel Application Scope Activity

To work with Excel, you must add an Excel Application Scope activity to the page. You'll need to provide the path to the Excel file. If the Excel file is in your project, it can be a relative path, otherwise a full path is needed.

There are a number of different activities that allow you to [write to Excel](https://youtu.be/6CCfT8HiwYI). I like the Append Range. This allows you to loop through multiple files and continuously add to Excel, rather than writing to the same cell each time, overwriting prior updates.

[image]

Above is a screenshot of a Web Scrape being pulled into UiPath as a DataTable, a print out of the first column of each row in the DataTable, and then finally the appending of the DataTable to Sheet1 of the Excel spreadsheet named scraped-data.xls. This image comes from a tutorial I did on how to have [UiPath scrape web text to Excel](https://youtu.be/NPpEUSp1AwY).